# Openflow Floodlight: How to force the server to run on a specific interface?

Tags: openflow

I've installed Floodlight in a Linux Ubuntu 18 server  with multiple Ethernet interfaces. Floodlight is running on the wrong interface, without connectivity to the openflow switches.  How can I force Floodlight to run on a specific interface?

I've installed Floodlight (master):

```
commit 18ef8882180d2f002c3c57c17d270ade885ef479 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Qing Wang <lucifer0909@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 10 01:38:54 2019 -0400
```

Starting it with the following:

```
sudo java -jar target/floodlight.jar
```

Comment: I found a way of changing the controller address in the Web GUI. Under 'active' , there is a button next to 'Controller Role' that allows changing the controller. However, I still need to find out how to select the interface at startup, or later, programmatically.

Comment: The file "target/bin/floodlightdefault.properties" contains some configurable properties. The prop "net.floodlightcontroller.core.internal.OFSwitchManager.openFlowAddresses" allows setting the IP address where the controller is listening. . Then use the modified config file with "sudo java -jar target/floodlight.jar  -cf path/to/config/floodlightdefault.properties"